# What is a "domain" in a Spring project?

Tags: java, spring

I notice a lot of Spring projects have a package named "domain", which seems to fit into the "model" part of the MVC model.

Why the name "domain", though? What convention / pattern, etc is this?

Comment: Happen to have a link to any of the duplicates? Didn't find see answer.

Comment: OK reopened, even this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913673/what-is-java-domain-model?lq=1) have 5 answers.

Comment: Thanks. That question had a lot more answers. Problem is if you don't know what something is, it's hard to ask the right questions. Like mine regarding domain in spring, when "What is a *java* domain model?" gives a lot more answers.

Comment: One first has to reason what the context is before one can ask a proper question. In your case: is it Spring specific? No, it is not, it is a term for which you are trying to find the definition. Is it Java specific then? Probably not, Java is but one tool of the trade within the larger world that is "software engineering". Try a silly Google for "programming what is a domain class" as an example, plenty of non-Java results.