# what is Domain Object Model (DOM)?

Tags: java

I am new to a java application where they are saying that the application uses domain object model (DOM) to communicate with other applications. But I don't know what "domain object model" is. I have searched stackoverflow, but couldn't find a clear answer. Can someone please explain this, to make it clear?

Comment: You are sure you're not talking about Document Object Model, right?

Comment: Is it domain object model? DOM refers to document object model in javascript. i think u are confusing with domain model

Comment: You could refer here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model

Comment: I know domain specific languages and i know Document Object Model, which describes a concecpt of how to parse and handle a structured document like xml (html).

Comment: Are you working on any web project that uses HTML or XML?

Comment: yeah I am sure its not Document object model.

Comment: If "they" are saying it, why don't you ask "they" to explain you what "they" mean?

Comment: Thats what everyone will do initially. But there is a problem that even they don't that exactly. Someone mentioned those things initially in application docs and they are simply following that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913673/what-is-java-domain-model