# Continuous improvement: Is it possible to specify the tests in advance?

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, specifications

I am used to "old fashioned" waterfall development cycles.
For a new project, continuous integration seems to better fit our need.

In waterfall, you have to specify the tests you will to implement in advance.

My questions:

- What is the usual way with continuous integration development cycles regarding test specification?
- If you don't specify the tests, can you imagine a way to specify them in advance?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At university we were taught that "test driven development" makes sense, especially if there is a proper coding specification.

If you're **not able** to write tests before coding -> the coding spec should be more specific / has issues.

I usually write unit-tests based on the coding spec for my java classes, which will afterwards be integrated and executed on our jenkins continuous integration server.

Forgive me if i am wrong but thats what i learned...

It always depends on the complexity of the required java classes, the trivial "domain" classes do not need a big specification [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913673/what-is-java-domain-model)

In most cases we try to specify how the Classes or Methods should work (in words) and also write down the some example values.

Lets say you should write a method that should check if a  value is in a specifig range:

```
// Example Specification:
// the method 'checkIfItsInRange' should return true when : the input lies within the range and it should be devidable by the distance value 
// Lets say the range goes from -30,00 to +30,00 with a distance from 0,25
// valid values :30, -30, 15.25, 15.50, 17.75 etc. -> return true
// invalid : -31, -30.01, +30.08, 0.4 etc. -> return false
// MissingParameterException when one of the Parameters is null

public boolean checkIfItsInRange throws MissingParameterException (BigDecimal from, BigDecimal to, BigDecimal distance, BigDecimal input) {
        // TODO implement depending on spec.
}
```

In this case you can already write some Unittests before you started to implement the method itself.

I hope that makes things a bit clearer.

Comment: Hi Springe, many thanks for your answer. To better understand your answer: What is the level of detail you have with the java classes you need to implement when you start coding? Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I missed the updates actually.